# How do i name the ng-app of angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-app

I am newly starting with the angular JS framework. The thing is i am stuck with the basic itself.

when i declare my tag as html tag as ng-app="" then the whole thing works fine. Other then  that what ever i give i am getting an error like the image given below [Code that is working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3j4n.png)

[After changing the name it shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrBBu.png)

The error is something like uncaught error:[$injector:modulerr]. I am being stuck with error of 2 days. No where solution this error is clearly given. someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: here's an example of what you need.... http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller... you need a controller there.

Comment: You need to update your angular module `angular.module('myApp', [])` to match the app name.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've supplied, it seems that you need to create a separate script file, where you would define your angular.module(); Something along these lines:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

You may also want to refer to Angular Tutorial/-s, eg:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02